# Iterator pattern example giving error in c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Stack
{
    int items[10];
    int sp;
  public:
    friend class StackIter;
    Stack()
    {
        sp =  - 1;
    }
    void push(int in)
    {
        items[++sp] = in;
    }
    int pop()
    {
        return items[sp--];
    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return (sp ==  - 1);
    }
    StackIter *createIterator() const // 2. Add a createIterator() member

};

class StackIter
{
    // 1. Design an "iterator" class
    const Stack *stk;
    int index;
  public:
    StackIter(const Stack *s)
    {
        stk = s;
    }
    void first()
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    void next()
    {
        index++;
    }
    bool isDone()
    {
        return index == stk->sp + 1;
    }
    int currentItem()
    {
        return stk->items[index];
    }
};

StackIter *Stack::createIterator() const
{
  return new StackIter(this);
}

bool operator == (const Stack &l, const Stack &r)
{
  // 3. Clients ask the container object to create an iterator object
  StackIter *itl = l.createIterator();
  StackIter *itr = r.createIterator();
  // 4. Clients use the first(), isDone(), next(), and currentItem() protocol
  for (itl->first(), itr->first(); !itl->isDone(); itl->next(), itr->next())
    if (itl->currentItem() != itr->currentItem())
      break;
  bool ans = itl->isDone() && itr->isDone();
  delete itl;
  delete itr;
  return ans;
}

int main()
{
  Stack s1;
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    s1.push(i);
  Stack s2(s1), s3(s1), s4(s1), s5(s1);
  s3.pop();
  s5.pop();
  s4.push(2);
  s5.push(9);
  cout << "1 == 2 is " << (s1 == s2) << endl;
  cout << "1 == 3 is " << (s1 == s3) << endl;
  cout << "1 == 4 is " << (s1 == s4) << endl;
  cout << "1 == 5 is " << (s1 == s5) << endl;
}
```

Compilation Error :

```
main.cpp:25:5: error: 'StackIter' does not name a type
     StackIter *createIterator()const // 2. Add a createIterator() member
main.cpp: In function 'bool operator==(const Stack&, const Stack&)':
main.cpp:68:22: error: 'const class Stack' has no member named 'createIterator'
   StackIter *itl = l.createIterator();
main.cpp:69:22: error: 'const class Stack' has no member named 'createIterator'
   StackIter *itr = r.createIterator();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: forward declare `class StackIter;` before `class Stack`

Comment: @sameerkn, that won't help, as he is trying to use the incomplete type before it is actually defined

Comment: Your missing a `;`  after ` StackIter *createIterator()const`  in the class definition for `Stack`

Comment: Leave about semicolon that I have added even though i am getting same errors as mentioned above...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon after "StackIter *createIterator()const". I added a semicolon. Then the program worked. There is no error.

Comment: Leave about semicolon even after adding semicolon I am getting error.